# How to disable Windows Files Sharing Wizard via Group Policy?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm setting up a Sophos Anti-Virus Server and in order to deploy need to shut off the Windows File Sharing Wizard (Not the actual file sharing) via group policy.  How is this done?  Is there a simple option to disable or will this have to be down via a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a strange requirement but you can use the Software Restrictions functionallity of Group Policy to deny the user the ability to run the shrpubw.exe executable, which is the Windows File Sharing Wizard.

Comment: I know weird huh?  I'm not sure why, but Sophos Installation within the network using Enterprise Console requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your users as standard/limited users and then the wizard will be inaccessable as to run it requires admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I had no need to turn that off during installation of any part of Sophos on our systems. If Sophos claims it's a requirement they should provide you with the step by step instructions. Give them a call.

Comment: they did provide step by step instructions, but on a client wide state... not through group policy